# Make a single global .so module available in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, gdbm

I have a program that needs to use the `dbm.gnu` module. This requires the external python3-gdbm debian package which is installed globally, but it's not available inside the virtualenv. As far as I can tell, this is not available to install via pip. I tried copying the file from `/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` to `venv/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/`, but the module is still not importable. Is there a way to somehow make this package available inside the virtualenv?

Using the `--system-site-packages` option of the `venv` module is not possible, because there are conflicts between some other global packages and the ones that are to be installed in the virtualenv.

Comment: I installed Debian package with `apt install -y python3-gdbm`, created a temp virtual env, copied `/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` to the venv's `lib/site-packages/` and imported it: `python3 -c "import _gdbm; print(_gdbm.__file__)"` -> `/home/phd/.virtualenvs/tmp-61654cf247e375cb/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_gdbm.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` No problem. What is the error message when you import `_gdbm`?

Comment: I compiled my Python 3.11 myself and it seems it has its own `_gdbm`: `python3 -c "import _gdbm; print(_gdbm.__file__)"` -> `/home/phd/.local/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_gdbm.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: You're right. I thought I had to copy it to venv/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload. I now tried venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages and it worked fine. I should have tried that before, I guess! :D